# Regex for just whole word (RE2)

Tags: python, regex, rethinkdb, re2

I am little bit lost in regex with rethinkdb. I tried so many possibilities, but the solution is always bad. I need to find in string just one the word and not other its shape. Usually, I am using for this just re.search and "\bword\b" < this work in TinyDB perfectly.
For example, I looking for word "les":

```
les < I need match
lesík < NO
za-les-nit < I need match
les'ns < I need match
odlesnit < NO
useless < NO
doles < NO
kolem je les, který ... < I need match
```

Like I wrote, I have good solution for TinyDB and its search regex function, but RethinkDB need something different. Maybe it is because of RE2, I dont know. Please help me someone. PS: If you know some RE2 online helper, send me link too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: RE2 supports `\b` as a word boundary. There is something else here.

Comment: @Mandy8055 yes, your solution is better then mine [link](https://regex101.com/r/sjXKDu/1) ..... you was fast :). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mandy8055 yes, absolutely. Thanks again. PS: really long regex for such small thing :)

Comment: Check if this meets your requierements https://regex101.com/r/u144z0/1

Comment: @Valijon it is good too, thanks a lot for you too.

Comment: @Jiří; I'm glad I could help=)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try:

```
(?:^|[[:punct:]]| )les(?:[[:punct:]]| |$)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`(?:)`** - Represents a non-capturing group.
- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the line respetively.
- **`|`** - Represents alternation.
- **`(?:^|[[:punct:]]| )`** - This ensures that only `les` appears at the start of the line or after the punctuation or after a white-space. **If white-space can come multiple times you can use `\s+`.**
- **`(?:[[:punct:]]| |$)`** - This part of the regex ensures that `les` should only be followed by a punctuation or a white-space or the end of line.

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex below.

#### RE2 demo

Comment: The way you are mastering regex, a day will come when people will start calling you a regex champ.